# How do I extract texts from tables in html while still maintaining its form? BS4/Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-table, python-re

I am dealing with very complex table elements in html.
There are multiple colspans that act as titles/sub-titles.
'td' (columns） and rows are sometimes not matched.
**How do I decompose the table to Pure text while still maintaining its readability?**
Is there a module/lib that can does the work for me?

[here's a example of the html table, but it could get more complex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b9qs.png)

Here's the code I tried with the table, it is very ugly yes but it sometimes work.

```
        for table in soup.find_all('table'):
            try: 
                sections = []
                current_section_header = None
                current_section_rows = []
                
                for row in table.find_all('tr'):
                    colspan_cell = row.find(['td', 'th'], colspan=True)
                    if colspan_cell:
                        if current_section_header:
                            sections.append((current_section_header, current_section_rows))
                        current_section_header = colspan_cell
                        current_section_rows = []
                    else:
                        current_section_rows.append(row)
                
                if current_section_header:
                    sections.append((current_section_header, current_section_rows))
                
                for header, rows in sections:
                    output_html_content += header.get_text(strip=True) + "<br><br>"
                    if len(rows) == 1:
                        for cell in rows[0].find_all(['td', 'th']):
                            output_html_content += cell.get_text(strip=True) + ' '
                    else:
                        headers = [cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in rows[0].find_all(['td', 'th'])]
                        for row in rows[1:]:
                            cells = row.find_all(['td', 'th'])
                            for header, cell in zip(headers, cells):
                                output_html_content += f"{header}: {cell.get_text(strip=True)}<br><br>"
                    output_html_content += "<br><br>"
```

I tried to do the colspan as a header/title. Then I match the text with the first row after colspan.

But when the data gets really complex, this doesn't work because the rows and columns aren't always matching. The p tags can be reading from top to bottom.

Comment: Welcome. Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Your question should also contain an expected output. Thanks